# How do you customize the default login error message in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I was browsing through the web and looking for solution on how can I modify this error message on Jetstream login:

[image]

Inside `app/Actions/Fortify` there is a file `CreateNewUser.php` where I can put some validation custom message on each field like this:

```
 public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:17'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ],[
            'name.required'=>'Name is required',
            'email.required'=>'Email is required',
            'phone.required'=>'Phone is required',
        ])->validate();
```

However, there is none for `Login.php`. I search the web and saw something about `vendors/laravel/fortify/src/Actions/AttemptToAuthenticate.php` but its consist with lots of code where I don't know where to put the customization:

```
   public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if (Fortify::$authenticateUsingCallback) {
            return $this->handleUsingCustomCallback($request, $next);
        }

        if ($this->guard->attempt(
            $request->only(Fortify::username(), 'password'),
            $request->filled('remember'))
        ) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $this->throwFailedAuthenticationException($request);
    }
```

Is there an easy way to customize the "The email field is required" to a different custom message in Laravel 8?

Been stuck for a couple of hours.

Comment: Have you tried following the Laravel docs? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: That's too general though. I believe Laravel 8 uses Jetstream for its authentication.  I believe somewhere there is a perfect steps to do this like what I did on the registration.

Comment: That error message can be overridden for the whole project via https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-custom-messages-in-language-files. Just because the linked documentation is "too general" doesn't mean you should ignore it... There are plenty of approaches in the documentation for handling this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize `FortifyServiceProvider` inside `App > Providers` by using the `Fortify::authenticateUsing` method and it should be called from the `boot` method.

```
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        } else {
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid!');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication)

Comment: That is what I am talking about.

Answer (score -1):

step 1 go to vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Requests\LoginRequest.php
step 2 in the loginRequest.php you will find two method

```js
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            Fortify::username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
```

step 3 add the following method below

```js
public function messages() {
  return = [
  'email.required' => 'email required',
  'password.required' => 'password required'
  ];
}
```

Comment: Could you add clear implementation to your answer?

Comment: kindly follow the steps above

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30326223)